# Scattering off spherical well - thermal neutron absorption and $1/v$ behaviour

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I am attempting to describe the $\sigma_{abs} \sim 1/v$ behaviour for thermal neutron absorption by heavy nuclei. In Krane's "Introductory Nuclear Physics" he first computes the cross-section for the case of 100% absorption, and then improves this result by multiplying by the transmission coefficient in a scattering off a squared well (cf. eq. 12-18 of the book).

Now, I thought I could do a bit better and consider a more realistic case of a spherical well. Since the incident energy is low (thermal neutrons), I need only consider $\ell=0$ states (no angular momentum). Then the wavefunction outside the well is a combination of in- and outgoing waves, $$\psi_{out} = Ae^{-ikr}/r + Be^{ikr}/r$$ where $k\sim \sqrt{E}$. The wave inside the well must be $$\psi_{in} = C \sin(qr)/r$$ with $q\sim \sqrt{E+V_0}$ (the other solution, $\cos(qr)/r$, is not regular at $r=0$).

But notice that the probability current inside the well is $j \sim \text{Im}(\psi_{in}^*\partial_r \psi_{in})$ and therefore vanishes. So the transmission coefficient is zero in this case. What should I make of this result? After all, bound states do exist and it shouldn't be impossible to transmit an incident wave to the inside of the well.

I also read about the treatment of bound states in spherical scatterings, and it is often stated that the s-wave saturates the unitarity bound and $\sigma = 4\pi/k^2$. But this would give a behaviour $\sigma \sim 1/v^2$, which is incorrect. Incidentally, this $1/v^2$ is also found by Krane BEFORE accounting for the transmission coefficient.

I'd appreciate if anyone could shed light on these issues, namely:

- (i) Why does the transmission coefficient (apparently) vanish for the spherical well?
- (ii) How to correctly account for the $1/v$ behaviour of the cross-section?